# Why my C++ Boost ASIO HTTP Client Returning Incomplete Response?

Tags: c++, http, boost, httpclient, boost-asio

I'm new to C++ and I'm just trying to implement a simple HTTP Client using Boost ASIO Sync Http Client; I copied the example from Boost's site, just modified it to return the response as string rather than writing to console.

My code is making a call and it's returning a response but it is partial - it cuts off after the 10th line...  I'm puzzled can someone please help me?

Here is my code and if you have Boost set up, you should be able to just copy/paste and run it.

I'm on Windows 7, using Visual Studio 2010 with Boost 1.47.

Thanks in advance.

-serkan

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

typedef boost::gregorian::date Calendar;



std::string httpClient(std::string host, std::string path){
    std::string res = "";

    try{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        // Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        tcp::resolver::query query(host, "http");
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;

        // Try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection.
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
        while(error && endpoint_iterator != end){
            socket.close();
            socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
        }

        if(error){ throw boost::system::system_error(error); }

        // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the server will close the socket 
        // after transmitting the response. This will allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
        boost::asio::streambuf request;
        std::ostream request_stream(&request);
        request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        request_stream << "Host: " << host << "\r\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

        // Send the request.
        boost::asio::write(socket, request);

        // Read the response status line.
        boost::asio::streambuf response;
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");

        // Check that response is OK.
        std::istream response_stream(&response);

        std::string http_version;
        response_stream >> http_version;

        unsigned int status_code;
        response_stream >> status_code;

        std::string status_message;
        std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
        if(!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/"){
            std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
        }
        if(status_code != 200){
            std::cout << "Response returned with status code " << status_code << "\n";
        }

        // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n\r\n");

        // Write whatever content we already have to output.
        if(response.size() > 0){
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << &response;
            res = oss.str();
        }

        // Read until EOF, writing data to output as we go.
        while(boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error)){
            //std::cout << &response; // don't want to print just return
        }

        if(error != boost::asio::error::eof){ throw boost::system::system_error(error); }

    }catch(std::exception& e){
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return res;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::cout << httpClient("download.finance.yahoo.com", "/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl,aig,msft,jpm,WFC,BAC,C,GS,USB,AXP,MS,MET,BK,PNC,PRU,SPG,AFL,TRV,COF,STT,ACE,BBT,CME,SCHW&f=sl1d1t1");

    return 0;
}
```

It should return:

"AAPL",384.62,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"AIG",23.85,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"MSFT",26.91,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"JPM",33.28,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"WFC",25.65,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"BAC",6.21,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"C",29.33,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"GS",101.66,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"USB",25.94,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"AXP",50.37,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"MS",16.36,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"MET",33.07,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"BK",21.51,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"PNC",53.87,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"PRU",54.05,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"SPG",127.97,"11/11/2011","4:02pm"
"AFL",44.87,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"TRV",58.43,"11/11/2011","4:04pm"
"COF",45.02,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"STT",41.24,"11/11/2011","4:02pm"
"ACE",71.24,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"BBT",23.58,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"CME",263.57,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"SCHW",12.36,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"

But it returns:

Date: Sat, 12 Nov 2011 21:34:23 GMT
P3P: policyref="http://p3p.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE GOV"
Cache-Control: private
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

"AAPL",384.62,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"AIG",23.85,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"MSFT",26.91,"11/11/2011","4:00pm"
"JPM",33.28,"11/11/2011","4:01pm"
"WFC",25.65,"11/11/

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the line

```
//std::cout << &response;
```

Now, I understand that you don't want the function to print out the result but to return it.  However, the loop that contains that commented-out line reads out the rest of the response, and now you are just throwing it away.  You need to capture it into your return-value variable.  A simple fix is to replace the commented-out line with

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << &response;
res += oss.str();
```

But that's not the cleanest way to do it – you should probably just let the stuff accumulate in `response` and convert it into a string at the end.

Comment: Thank you ibid, I've removed the empty header, and commented that I actually didn't need the console printing - rather I wanted function to return the response.  In my original post I've only had 3 stock tickers which works fine but when I add more tickers (when response gets longer) it gets cut off.  I've corrected main() code and I was wondering if you could give it another try?  Best wishes

Comment: It's basically the same problem, so I just edited it to correspond to your question better.